# Accumulating Curried Function (SML)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, currying

I have a set of problems that I've been working through and can't seem to understand what the last one is asking. Here is the first problem, and my solution to it:

> a) Often we are interested in computing ∑<sub><sub>*i*=*m*..*n*</sub></sub> *f*(*i*), the sum of function values *f*(*i*) for *i* = *m* through *n*. Define `sigma f m n` which computes ∑<sub><sub>*i*=*m*..*n*</sub></sub> *f*(*i*). This is different from defining `sigma (f, m, n)`.

```
fun sigma f m n = if (m=n) then f(m) else (f(m) + sigma f (m+1) n);
```

The second problem, and my solution:

> b) In the computation of sigma above, the index i goes from current
>       i to next  value i+1. We may want to compute the sum of f(i) where i
>       goes from  current i to the next, say i+2, not i+1. If we send this
>       information as an  argument, we can compute more generalized
>       summation. Define ‘sum f  next m n’ to compute such summation, where
>       ‘next’ is a function to compute  the next index value from the
>       current index value. To get ‘sigma’ in (a), you  send the successor
>       function as ‘next’.

```
fun sum f next m n = if (m>=n) then f(m) else (f(m) + sum f (next) (next(m)) n);
```

And the third problem, with my attempt:

> c) Generalizing sum in (b), we can compute not only summation but also
>   product and other forms of accumulation. If we want to compute sum in
>   (b),  we send addition as an argument; if we want to compute the
>   product of  function values, we send multiplication as an argument for
>   the same  parameter. We also have to send the identity of the
>   operator. Define ‘accum  h v f next m n’ to compute such accumulation,
>   where h is a two-variable  function to do accumulation, and v is the
>   base value for accumulation. If we  send the multiplication function
>   for h, 1 for v, and the successor function as  ‘next’, this ‘accum’
>   computes ∏<sub><sub>*i*=*m*..*n*</sub></sub> *f*(*i*). Create examples whose ‘h’ is not addition or
>   multiplication, too.

```
 fun accum h v f next m n = if (m>=n) then f(m) else (h (f(m)) (accum (h) (v) (f) (next) (next(m)) n));
```

In problem C, I'm unsure of what i'm suppose to do with my "v" argument. Right now the function will take any interval of numbers m - n and apply any kind of operation to them. For example, I could call my function

```
accum mult (4?) double next3 1 5;
```

where double is a doubling function and next3 adds 3 to a given value. Any ideas on how i'm suppoes to utilize the v value?

Answer (score 0):

This set of problems is designed to lead to implementation of accumulation function. It takes

- `h` - combines previous value and current value to produce next value
- `v` - starting value for `h`
- `f` - function to be applied to values from `[m, n)` interval before passing them to `h` function
- `next` - computes next value in sequence
- `m` and `n` - boundaries

Here is how I'd define `accum`:

```
fun accum h v f next m n = if m >= n then v else accum h (h (f m) v) f next (next m) n
```

Examples that were described in `C` will look like this:

```
fun sum x y = x + y;
fun mult x y = x * y;
fun id x = x;

accum sum 0 id next 1 10; (* sum [1, 10) staring 0 *)
accum mult 1 id next 1 10; (* prod [1, 10) starting 1 *)
```

For example, you can calculate sum of numbers from `1` to `10` and plus `5` if you pass `5` as `v` in first example.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions will make more sense if you consider the possibility of an *empty* interval.

- The "sum" of a single value *n* is *n*. The sum of *no* values is zero.
- The "product" of a single value *n* is *n*. The product of *no* values is one.
- A list of a single value *n* is `[n]` (`n::nil`). A list of *no* values is `nil`.

Currently, you're assuming that *m* ≤ *n*, and treating *m* = *n* as a special case that returns `f m`. Another approach is to treat *m* > *n* as the special case, returning `v`. Then, when *m* = *n*, your function will automatically return `h v (f m)`, which is the same as `(f m)` (provided that *v* was selected properly for this *h*).

To be honest, though, I think the *v*-less approach is fine when the function's arguments specify an interval of the form [*m*,*n*], since there's no logical reason that such a function would support an empty interval. (I mean, [*m*,*m*−1] isn't so much "the empty interval" as it is "obvious error".) The *v*-ful approach is chiefly useful when the function's arguments specify a list or set of elements in some way that really *could* conceivably be empty, e.g. as an `'a list`.